# module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'tensorflow_backend'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I run my code where I am trying to use tensor flow as backend and I do the following:

```
import tensorflow
KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
import keras
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

I get the following error:

```
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'tensorflow_backend'
```

However, when I run the same piece of code on Jupyter notebook, it works and gives me the following output:

```
['/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0']
```

And this output means that tensowflow is installed. I don't get it why I get the above mentioned error when I run the same script through terminal. I am in the same environment in both cases. Insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code you are trying to understand, Is Tensorflow installed and using GPU ?

In Tensorflow 2.x, the same can be known in the following way

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

The following will also return the name of your GPU devices.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

If a `non-GPU` version of the package is installed, the function would also return `False`. Use `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda` to validate if TensorFlow was build with CUDA support.

*Note: From TF 2.0, onwards `Keras` are integrated with `Tensorflow` as `tf.keras`*, please use this module `tf.keras.backend`